# Using aes_string in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

df <- data.frame(type = rep(c("cons", "dyn"), each = 15),
                 rain = sample(1:40, 30, replace = T), 
                 tmax =  sample(20:40, 30, replace = T), 
                 tmin = sample(1:10, 30, replace = T))
pdf("plot.pdf")

for(i in 2:ncol(df)){

   variable.name <- names(df)[i] 

    p1 <- ggplot(df, aes_string(variable.name)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~type)

    # I want to plot `variable.name` of `cons` and `dyn` against each other

    p2 <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x = variable.name[type == "cons"], y = variable.name[type == "dyn"])) + geom_point() 

    grid.arrange(p1, p2)
 }
dev.off()
```

At the moment, the `p2` plot is not working which is because I cannot subset the columns.

Comment: "I want to plot `variable.name` of `cons` and `dyn` against each other" Then you need to rearrange (`dcast`, `spread`) your data so that they are in different columns.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to do it. I was just wondering if there's something I can do in the `aes_string(x = variable.name[type == "cons"], y = variable.name[type == "dyn"]))` straightway but maybe I am just overkilling it

Comment: Have you checked what `variable.name[type == "cons"]` returns? Your proposed approach can't work.

Comment: I know it does not work and hence my question :-).

Comment: It not only doesn't work, it can't work in the ggplot2 framework. It's fundamentally against the design.

Comment: Okay. I will then just change my approach. Thanks